# NiFi: how to write local files information in all the nodes?

Tags: apache-nifi

NiFi version: 1.5

Environment: 3 node HDF

NiFi flow:
ListFTP(primary) -> FetchFTP -> PutFile -> ExecuteScript

i get the file from the source location and save in destination location. After which, i write python code(ExecuteScript) to track the files written successfully in local file system(/var/log/nifi/status/status.csv).

below is my python code:

```
from org.apache.nifi.processors.script import ExecuteScript 
import datetime

flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile != None):
     fn = flowFile.getAttribute('filename')
     timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
     fopn = open('/var/log/nifi/status/status.csv','a')
     res = "\n" + "timestamp" + "fn" + "SUCCESS"
     fd.write(res)
     fd.close()
     session.transfer(flowFile,ExecuteScript.REL_SUCCESS)
```

Execution = All nodes

the file information are written into the local path(status.csv) but it is written only in one instance.
i want to update the file(status.csv) in all the nodes.

TIA.

Comment: "All nodes" actually means "any node". to run something on all nodes you have to ingest initial data on all nodes.

Comment: Agree with @daggett, your FetchFTP runs on primary only but then any node in the cluster can pick up that file, so one of the node that got the job will have the status.csv.

Comment: yes i understand. but if i dont give ListFTP as primary, it would fetch same data three times. right? how to overcome this step?

Comment: @daggett. is there any way we can save to three nodes?

Comment: you could finish current flow by putting let's say 3 rows into a database (or 3 files on a shared folder). those 3 items have to be identified by a node id. and make subflow that triggered by those items on all nodes. (each node have to take own item)

Comment: @daggett. could you please elaborate.

Comment: @natarajank, could you explain why do you need this? why for example not to put this state file into a shared (between all 3 nodes) directory ? or put this status into a database or cache ? so you'll not be linked to a nodes...

Comment: @daggett. i am doing poc where we have requirement to track the status of the file transfer successfully/failed in the local file. For example, file status would be like (timestamp,filename,status) Also, we should not create shared directort neither we have database.